# How am I supposed to figure out the ingredients for bitter-melon juice?

Tags: yakuza-3

One of the side-missions (or as they are called in-game, "substories") in Yakuza 3 has you collecting ingredients for making bitter-melon juice. Some old lady is making the juice and she tells you to bring her the following:

- Goya - bitter melon (though this possibly appears as "Balsam Pear" in the American version of the game, based on [this FAQ](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/950186-yakuza-3/faqs/55807). Search for "Ryuukyuugai no Nanafushigi Sono4")
- Kuruzata - brown sugar ("black sugar" in the American version)
- Dugwai - aloe
- Basanai - banana, you can replace it with the more expensive "island banana."
- Lemon - well, it's a lemon, though you can replace it with a [Shikwasa](http://www.jpn-okinawa.com/en/products/shiikwaasaa/)

The only reason I knew which word meant what is because of the FAQ I linked to. Is there any way for me to have figured this out in-game, or does the game expect me to be Japanese/look it up?

Comment: You're playing the Japanese version then?

Comment: European, actually. Of course, the FAQ could possibly be based on the Japanese version, but I assumed it was based on the American version seeing how I found the exact same terms ("black sugar", for instance) in places where I doubt most users are Japanese-savvy.

Comment: Ah, I see. I did manage to finish this mission, using the descriptions of the items given by the old lady and by looking at what was on offer in the market. (I'm also playing the EU version.)

Comment: She gives out descriptions of the items? Do you have to talk to her again for that? All she gave me were the names, and I rushed off to the public market hoping the game would clue me in during the mission.

Comment: Ugh, my memory of this mission is very vague - I did it quite a long time ago. Thinking about it now, I remember reading some descriptions, but it may have been from a faq rather than from the game. Sorry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, you're suppose to get each ingredient one by one. I believe that every time you give her a correct ingredient (assuming you have not collected them all), she'll tell you she doesn't have enough to make the juice and gives you a description of one that you are missing. (e.g. if you are missing the bananas, she'll go "Basanai, silly. You know, yellow and sweet?")

Since the shopkeeper speaks in an Okinawan dialect, it's supposed to be hard to understand what she means. Kind of like how people from the Midwest/NW (of the US) call [carbonated beverages](http://bigthink.com/ideas/21360?page=all) "pop," while people in the NE call them "soda," and Southerners refer to them, generically, as "coke."